# Moment Sequence in l²

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, moments

I have the following problem/question:

For which finite regular complex measures $\mu$ is the moment sequence
$$
\left(\int_{[-1,1]}t^k\,d\mu\right)_{k\in\mathbb N}
$$
a member of $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$?

Clearly, the measures in question may not have mass in $1$ or $-1$. Moreover, if the (closed) support of a measure is contained in $(-1,1)$ then the associated moment sequence lies in $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$. But I cannot say more. Can anyone of you? I think there should be literature on such problems, but I cannot find anything on the net.

Comment: If $\mu$ is positive, then (by just summing) the sequence is in $\ell^2$ if and only if $1/(1-st)\in L^1(\mu\otimes\mu)$, and this is what it is, in my opinion. For complex measures, there's a similar characterization that now involves a density $e^{i\alpha(t)}$. (In fact, I don't think having complex measures changes much because for at least one of $k$ even or odd, there won't be substantial cancellations.)